# Did Russian instructors help Hamas in the 2023 attacks against Israel?

Tags: russia, israel, palestine, israel-hamas-war

Gulag.net, a Russian anti-establishment website, posted a video ["Прикрывайте!Прикрывайте!" Среди нападавших на Израиль были русскоговорящие инструкторы. ЧВК Вагнер?](https://youtu.be/U-ZRURrUGyA), which translates to *'"Cover! Cover!" Among the attackers on Israel were Russian-speaking instructors. PMC Wagner?'*

At 0:06 of the above video posted by , we hear Russian words "Прикрывайте! Прикрывайте!"

Former Ukrainian president Poroshenko [has](https://www.euractiv.com/section/global-europe/interview/poroshenko-wagner-signature-behind-hamas-attack/) made a similar claim, in broad terms:

> The former Ukrainian president Petro Poroshenko told Euractiv he was “absolutely sure” that instructors from the Russian mercenary group Wagner were transferred from Syria to Gaza to help prepare the terrorist attacks on Israel on 7 October. [...]
>
> “I’m absolutely sure that the Russian Wagner instructors in Syria were transferred to Hamas in Gaza and participated in the training of terrorists to prepare the absolutely barbaric attack on Israel from the Gaza strip.”

Did Russians instructors help Hamas in the latest invasion?

Comment: Putting my tin-foil hat here for a sec: how do we know the audio is 100% from that footage, and not something added on top etc.? Anyhow, Poroshenko has made a [similar claim](https://www.euractiv.com/section/global-europe/interview/poroshenko-wagner-signature-behind-hamas-attack/) so this is definitely notable, but I'm not sure how answerable, for now. There are reasons to be skeptical, like Wagner not normally working with Islamists, but rather against them.

Comment: OTOH Hamas and al-Assad (Wagner's main  client in the region) have mended fences last year https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/hamas-leaders-meet-assad-damascus-turn-page-2022-10-19/ And some time after that Hamas started to post training videos of them storming Israeli positions https://www.cbsnews.com/news/israel-gaza-hamas-months-old-training-videos-foreshadowed-deadly-assault/ (Which got dismissed as just propaganda, I guess.)

Comment: The sound quality is bad, so it's hard to hear exactly what they are saying. But if they are indeed saying cover, the. The soldier don't execute the command. We don't see them laying covering fire so either they did not follow orders or they said something else.

Comment: @SIMEL playing devil's advocate here: assuming the provided word is heard correctly - the order could be directed at someone not in the frame of the video. Also, this word in Russian could also mean "cover <something> up", or (reaching a bit) "close <something>".

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov, the meaning is "cover by firing [bullets]", not "cover by roofing"

Comment: I have seen this video few time: for around a week in the beginning, there were no russian heard. However, it could be possible, that I have seen a somewhat different videos, i.e. from the POV of another person, but in the exact same place and time.

Comment: Could be EVPs too...or at least based on the same psychological phenomenon.